# Which layer is saved by CBOW?

Tags: word-embeddings, word2vec

The word2vec model saves its layer weights as embeddings.
But do CBOW and skipgram both store the input layer weights?

I know they learn different embeddings for the words in the context and for the word as center word.
CBOW features the context embeddings in the input layer and Skip-gram the center words.

I had a look at the C-Code and it looks like they are both storing the input layer syn0 as word vectors.

Am I right in my understanding?

Are the CBOW vectors therefore the context vectors and not the center word vectors as in skip-gram?

Why does CBOW not store the center word embeddings (output layer)?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, both input and output weight layers could be used as word embeddings, and the input one is used by convention.

One of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46065773/why-we-use-input-hidden-weight-matrix-to-be-the-word-vectors-instead-of-hidden-o?rq=1) refers to a paper in which both input and output weights are used (Section 2 in [A Dual Embedding Space Model for Document Ranking](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.01137.pdf)).

Comment: Thank you! So in CBOW the embeddings are the ones from the context words by convention? Thats what I thought.